# Preparing Invocation Builder to send query parameters - jax rs

Tags: java, url, jax-rs, query-string

I want to make a GET to with an url that looks like this:

```
private static final String TEMPLATE_URI = /tfe/{param1}/{param2};
```

For this I made a map:

```
final Map<String, Object> templateValues = new HashMap<>();
templateValues.put(param1, someValue1);
templateValues.put(param2, someValue2);
```

Then i use invocationBuilder to match the values up and send it like so:

```
final Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = getInvocationBuilder(TEMPLATE_URI, templateValues);
final Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

The getInvocationBuilder looks like this:

```
protected Invocation.Builder getInvocationBuilder(final String templateUri, final Map<String, Object> templateValues) {
    final String baseUrl = ApplicationProperties.getInstance().getProperty("baseUrl");
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    final WebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl);
    final WebTarget template = target.path(templateUri);
    final WebTarget resource = template.resolveTemplates(templateValues);
    final Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return invocationBuilder;
}
```

QUESTION: this all works just fine, but now i also want to send query parameters, which are not obligatory. I want to read them on the receiver from an url that looks like this:

/tfe/{param1}/{param2}?{param3}=3&{param4}=4

How do i modify the getInvocationBuilder to handle those? I figured out how to get them on the receiving end, but here i need help to stuff them into the invocationbuilder somehow. THANK YOU!

Comment: You need to use `webTarget.queryParam`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES peeskillet !

You are right, ive modified the getInvocationBuilder method and now it should work:

```
    protected Invocation.Builder getInvocationBuilder(final String templateUri, final Map<String, Object> templateValues,
        final Map<String, Object> queryParameterValues) {
    final String baseUrl = ApplicationProperties.getInstance().getProperty("ucp.baseUrl");
    final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    final WebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl);
    final WebTarget template = target.path(templateUri);
    final WebTarget resource = template.resolveTemplates(templateValues);
    if (queryParameterValues != null) {
        final Iterator iterator = queryParameterValues.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
            resource.queryParam((String) pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
        }
    }
    final Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = resource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return invocationBuilder;
}
```

The query parameters are given to the method as another map and the method is now called like this:

```
        final Map<String, Object> queryParameterValues = new HashMap<>();
    queryParameterValues.put(REQUIRED_OTD_FIELDS_QUERY_PARAM, REQUIRED_OTD_FIELDS_QUERY_PARAM_VALUE);
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You could have another map for query parameters and do something as following:

```java
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
    target.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```